# How to query embedded document in rails & mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a class model, a student model and an attendance model. Attendance is embedded in Student to improve the performance.

I want to show number of all students in Class, number of present students, number of absent student & percentage of attendance. I am a newbie in Mongodb and i would appreciate any help. Thanks you for your time.

```
class Klass
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_and_belongs_to_many :students

  field :name, type: String
end

class Student
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_and_belongs_to_many :klasses
  embeds_many :attendances

  field :name, type: String
end

class Attendance
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :student

  field :status, type: Integer # 1 = Present, 2 = Absent
  field :klass_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
end
```

Comment: Can you try my solution and let me know what you get, in comments?

Comment: any update? Did it work? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No, still struggling with date issue...

Comment: did you try this ? `@class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1', 'attendences.created_at.gte' => Date.today).count`

Comment: yes i tried but...it didnt work, return 0.

Comment: There was a typo: `@class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1', 'attendances.created_at.gte' => Date.today).count`


Could you please try this : `@class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1', attendances: {:created_at.gte => Date.today} ).count`

Comment: I have tried above solutions...no success and try `@class.students.where( attendances: {:created_at.gte => Date.today.beginning_of_day, :status => 1}).count` but still no success...:(

Comment: try this: `@class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1', 'attendances.created_at' => {'$gte' => Date.today} ).count` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by following technique.

```
@students_present_today = @class.students.where({ attendances: { '$elemMatch' => {status: 1, :created_at.gte => Date.today} } }).count
@students_absent_today = @class.students.where({ attendances: { '$elemMatch' => {status: 2, :created_at.gte => Date.today} } }).count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these:

```
@class = Klass.where(name: 'something').first

@total_students = @class.students.count

@present_students = @class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1').count

@absent_students = @class.students.where('attendances.status' => '2').count

@p_s_today = @class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1', 'attendances.created_at' => {'$gte' => Date.today} ).count

@a_s_today = @class.students.where('attendances.status' => '2', 'attendances.created_at' => {'$gte' => Date.today} ).count
```

Comment: @absent_students also works... thanx... but how do i restrict them by date (today)

Comment: `"attendances.c_at.gte" => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day` i add this but it doesnt work

Comment: @class.students.where('attendances.status' => '1', 'attendences.created_at.gte' => Date.today).count

Comment: @Murtza, can you try my last query ? Hope this would solve your all problems :)

Comment: @class.students.where( "attendances.c_at.gte" => Date.today, "attendances.status" => 1).count doesnt work